# How to keep IoC container in one place, while inner classes need to create dependencies after beeing constructed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject-2

I started to use Ninject , on this relatively small project and i have run into a problem: i have this class

```
class SomeService : ISomeService
```

that depends on

```
class BizLogicModule : IBizLogicModule
```

that in turn depends on

```
class DataRepository : IDataRepository
```

the `DataRepository` has a ctor that looks like:

```
DataRepository(BizEntityModel context)
```

Now, i need to be able to use a single instance of `BizEntityModel` across more than one `IDataRepository` instance. 
 I also need to create `IDataRepository`'s along the life of a `IBizLogicModule`. The `IBizLogicModule` does not know about Ninject and i want to keep it that way.

so my problem is:
how to wire all that up, using the Ninject kernel, while:

1. not having to pass the kernel instance around the layers.
2. leaving the code readable close to what it was prior Ninject (i was just new'ing using a factory method).

The simple part of the wiring i got so far is:

```
Bind<SomeService>().To<ISomeService>();
Bind<BizLogicModule>().To<IBizLogicModule>();
Bind<DataRepository>().To<IDataRepository>(); 
Bind<BizEntityModel>().To<BizEntityModel>(); //ToSelf()
// .WithConstructorArgument(context => Kernel.Get<BizEntityModel>)
```

Your guidance is very much appreciated

**EDIT:** Thanks for your answers! 
here's some more data that was requested:
`BizEntityModel` is registered with Ninject (code updated).

if i understand correctly: i can create instances of `IDataRepository` in `IBizLogicModule` using a 'factory method'. but that leaves me with:
 **1)** i need to pass a `BizEntityModel` to the factory method, some times its bran new and sometimes its an existing instance. using the factory method, it will create anew one every time. 
 **2)** is this a problem that `SomeService` is in another assembly, and only it has a ref to Ninject.dll ?

Comment: What rule has this sometimes new, sometimes reused?

Comment: i am using a 'unit of work' style with the repository, sometimes making more than one change and saving them in a transaction. in simple cases i juts use an instance for just one change. (not sure i answered what the rule is since its the logic itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you register BizEntityModel with Ninject? If so, you should be able to tell Ninject to supply one and only one instance of a BizEntityModel for every request for the lifetime of the container, or even the program, without having to define and register a traditional singleton instance of BizEntityModel. Even if you have to work with a factory method and Ninject won't let you singleton-scope that registraion, if you have to you can eager-load the object and then register the instance for the dependency as a singleton.

IBizLogicModule should never have to know about Ninject; Ninject should know about BizLogicModule. Try creating an IDataRepository registration that will provide a factory method (factory-scoped so a new instance is created per call), then pass that factory method as a dependency to IBizLogicModule, which will use it when it needs to create IDataRepositories. You're basically passing through the IoC's resolution capabilities to provide a factory class in IBizLogicModule. If you do that for a lot of different class types on IBizLogicModule, you're basically creating a service locator which I would personally avoid, but one or two is a perfectly valid Factory/Creator pattern.

Comment: after re reading what you said  few times , i think i understand what can be done, so i marked as 'answer'. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I repeat the question a like I understood it:

1. Exactly one BizEntityModel instance exists per BizLogicModule instance (They do not have a reference to each other)
2. Whenever BizLogicModule creates a DataRepository this BizEntityModel is reused
3. There are several BizLogicModules

If this is correct the second example in the NamedScope extension documentation should fit for you. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki/InNamedScope

Make sure that you read the complete docu of this extension: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki

Comment: hi  ,just to explain myself better, the first assumption is not correct. there may be more than one `BizEntityModel` in a `BizLogicModule `, and sometimes one instance will be used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below assumes that you're asking how to resolve many instances of `IDataRepository` in one `IBizLogicModule`. Otherwise this question will be too easy :-)

Usually good IoC containers have an ability to inject Factories/Factory methods. I do not have much experience with NInject and I haven't found as good solutions as I know for other containers but [HERE](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/b419ccfa66bb05e7?pli=1) you can see example how the main task can be achieved. The only issue here is that you will have to implement a factory on your own and pull `IResolutionContext` there but anyway this factory will allow you isolating rest of your code (`IBizLogicModule`) from IoC specifics because it will have only `IDataRepositoryFactory`  dependency.

Comment: your assumption is correct , but i also need to supply an argument to the factory. (that argument is a `BizEntityModel` that i may have hanging around, rather that a new one). i updated the question to better reflect that, can you take a look ?